Maven compiled spring-boot not including security config but works in Intelij
I have a spring-boot server written in kotlin that has its own security configuration:
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true,
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true)
class DefaultSecurityConfig (
    private val userDetailsService: MyUserDetailsService,
) {

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
        println("Custom Security Configuration Loaded")
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity, jwtFilter: JWTFilter): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .csrf { it.disable() }
            .cors{ it.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())}
            .authorizeHttpRequests {
                it
                    .requestMatchers(PUBLIC_API_PATH, STATIC_PATH, PUBLIC_PATH, ERROR_PATH).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(API_PATH).hasAuthority(USER_ROLE)
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .sessionManagement {
                it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            }
            .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(): UserDetailsService {
        return userDetailsService
    }

    [...]

}

When running the application in Intelij everything compiles and runs fine. The auto security configuration is overwritten and the above class was used for introducing the security filter chain. But when packaging the application with maven using mvn clean package or mvn package spring-boot:repackage all security configuration were disregarded and the default was used showing this in the startup log:
2024-11-08T07:03:11.145+01:00  WARN 52923 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 8ed64c5c-6b93-4fbb-a2a7-e9af2ae64032

I tried adding this in the DefaultSecurityConfig class to see if the class is beeing created but that was not the case. It did show the log when starting through the IDE.
@PostConstruct
fun init() {
    println("Custom Security Configuration Loaded")
}

I also tried using different pom versions and configurations but noting changed. I could edit my application.yml to exclude config beans that still does not start my normal classes.
It feels to me like it picks up the application.yml and pom.xml but all the code in not beeing used during the compilation.
Its probably something pretty stupid but any pointer would be helpful.
Pom.xml:
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/openapi/src/main/java</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/test/kotlin</source>
                                <source>target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <jvmTarget>17</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>


I made a workaround by removing the sourceDirs and including the auto generated code that should have been compiled through adding it as a maven library
